# Is reversing the menu order on mobile navigation a good idea?

Tags: mobile, navigation, menu, ordering

I work at a place where they are keen on reversing the order of the navigation items on mobile menus.

The menu is at the bottom of the screen, and the order is reversed, so Home (basically the three most important menu items) are on the bottom of the list while on desktop they would be most left of the list:

Desktop menu:

```
Home | About Us | Pricing | Whaterver
```

Mobile menu

```
Whatever
Pricing
About Us
Home
```

I have found one case online [here](https://uxmovement.com/mobile/why-mobile-menus-belong-at-the-bottom-of-the-screen/) where this practise is suggested.
To me, it is very counter intuitive since logically the most important thing is on top, and not on the bottom of the list.

I can see that the bottom items are more easily reachable with the thumb like this, but I imagine users would be spending more time trying to find the Home button in the list, since they would start to look at the top of the list.

Is there any extensive testing done on this subject? Any insights?

Comment: Hi vanMeerdervoort, do you have a link to the case study you mentioned?

Comment: Why is it you believe that "home" is the most important? What is so important about it? Also, I doubt you will find many users want to learn "about you" as a priority over how much you cost (pricing). So your order of importance seems a bit unjustified.

Comment: Is the menu drop-down (or, well, drop-*up*)? If yes, and it is at the bottom of the screen, then it means the bottommost option is the closest to the point you clicked/tapped to open the menu.

Comment: It breaks the left to right / top to bottom F pattern of Western Culture users.

Comment: @tbonejenkins this is the article I meant: https://uxmovement.com/mobile/why-mobile-menus-belong-at-the-bottom-of-the-screen/

Comment: @musefan that's not specifically what I believe, but what my employer believes. Basically they deem the three first menu items most important, whatever they are.

Comment: Why are they so keen on that at your workplace?

Answer (score 2):

I would say this breaks directly Consistency Usability Standard.

Taken from NNgroup website:
"Jakob's Law states that people spend most of their time using digital products other than yours. Users’ experiences with those other products set their expectations. Failing to maintain consistency may increase the users'cognitive load by forcing them to learn something new."